# How to run a tensorflow model in parallel? Do I need to reprogram the model?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a simple way in tensorflow to make any model run in parallel without reprogramming the model? Like in PyTorch using the [DataParallel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html) method

I am new to tensorflow so any reference or code example is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can modify the config proto of tensorflow and use:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': GPU},
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=NBR_THREADS,
                        intra_op_parallelism_threads=NBR_THREADS)

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
   <run_your_code>
```